How to display azure databricks table data with html formated data in logic app email notification
i want to send  Azure ADB table data into Email using azure logic app
i want to send  Azure ADB table data into Email using azure logic app with HTML formatted display.
how to send  ADB table data into email notification using logic app

Can you provide your sample input, is it in json format?

Notebook exited: ["{"Metrics_Name":"Booking","Quarter_Name":"2023-Q2","Snapshot_key":20240717,"Profit_Center_number":"1010","Profit_Center_Desc":"AC/DC","Net_Amount_LC":1934392821.44}", "{"Metrics_Name":"Booking","Quarter_Name":"2023-Q1","Snapshot_key":20240717,"Profit_Center_number":"1010","Profit_Center_Desc":"AC/DC","Net_Amount_LC":1682202379.64}", "{"Metrics_Name":"Booking","Quarter_Name":"2023-Q3","Snapshot_key":20240717,"Profit_Center_number":"1010","Profit_Center_Desc":"AC/DC","Net_Amount_LC":1770815437.98}"

Can you add in question.

You can use below design to send as table in mail:
Firstly get the data from Databricks Notebook. To get Databricks Note book result follow this SO-Thread's answer provided @Rakesh Govindula and this SO-thread.
Take the result and then use parse json to parse it and then follow below design:
Then use that data like below:

Then in next action:

then:

In Compose 2:
<style>
#testID table, table th, table td {border: 1px solid #32CD32}
</style>
<div id="testID">
@{body('Create_HTML_table')}
</div>

Output:


i tried with above steps but still facing issue:

{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: r. Path 'Pipelineoutput', line 6, position 20.'."}}

there is something wrong with your json, otherwise it will work fine as it worked for me.

Thanks for your quick response, input data would be dynamic not static as above inputs

there is no need for the data to be static or dynamic it just need array of json that's it. This Design will work if done correctly.
